# Opening page based on link clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a table in a page first.php that may contain thousands of tuples. It goes like:-

```
UsedId    Name   and so on
1         A   
2         B
....
```

What I then I have is that you can click on the UserId and it will take you to the page second.php. I have a session variable:-

```
<?php $_SESSION["newsession"]=1?>
```

I want this session variable to be the UserId of the user that was clicked on. Then, it should be displayed in the second.php page.

I was successfully able to make link to go to the second page, I also know about session variables pretty much, but I don't know how I can display the userid of the user which was clicked. Please help. Thanks

Comment: `<a href="second.php?userId=$userIdFromDB>` and at `second.php` you can user `$_GET['userId']`

Comment: @Martijn What exactly should I replace $userIdFromDB by? What I tried was <a href="http://localhost/second.php?userId=".<?php $row['userid']?>> and it doesn't work... Can you please help a bit more

Comment: You're almost there. Analise the result. Debug, step for step. Check out _how_ it's different from what you want and correct it. This is so basic that we cant help you, you have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: Did it using <a href=<?php echo "http://localhost/checkId.php?userId=".$row['userid'];?>> . Thanks!